# How to call another component using Routerlink in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React RouterLink not working. i have a component like profile.js i want to redirect that component by onclick. so o tried many way to do this. and i dont understand router and router as link. can you refer me some exact documentation about this.

here is my code:

```
//Nav bar

<Transitions in={open} {...TransitionProps}>
   <MainCard>
     <CardContent>
        <List component="nav" className={classes.navContainer}>
            <ListItem className={classes.listItem}
             sx={{ borderRadius: theme.palette.borderRadius + "px", }}
             selected={selectedIndex === 0}
             onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
             component={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
             <RouterLink {...props} to="../Profile/profile"/>
              ))} >
                 <ListItemIcon>
                     <IconSettings stroke={1.5} size="1.3rem" />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText
                     primary={<Typography variant="body2">Account Settings</Typography> }/>
                  </ListItem>
     </CardContent>
   </MainCard>
</Transitions>
```

This component need to redirect when i click menu.

```
//Profile.js

import React from "react";
import "./profile.css";

function profile() {
  return (
     <card>
       <div class="main-content">
         <p>Profile</p>
       </div>
     </card>
)};
```

Routes:

```
//CustomRoutes.js

import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./component/layout/MainLayout/Header/Profile/profile";

export default [
<Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />,
];
```

App.js

```
//App.js

import customLayout from "./component/layout/customLayout/customLayout";
import profile from "./component/layout/MainLayout/Header/Profile/profile";
import AdminBuilder from "./AdminBuilder";
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";

class App extends Component {
render() {

return (

<AdminBuilder profile={profile} />

 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main file, i think it would be app.js
you need to tell your profile path to which location it should go. for example:

```
            <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
```

Now you can use this /profile path into your

```
             <RouterLink {...props} to="../Profile/profile"/>
```

but its better to use `<Link to="/profile"> </Link>`
Hope it make since.

**#Update:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./component/layout/MainLayout/Header/Profile/profile";

**what is this export default?**

export default [
<Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />,
];
```

**#Update2**
in your app please make it like this>

```
 import React from 'react'
import customLayout from "./component/layout/customLayout/customLayout";
import profile from "./component/layout/MainLayout/Header/Profile/profile";
import AdminBuilder from "./AdminBuilder";
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <AdminBuilder profile={profile} />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: could you please share here what you've tried?

Comment: I shared code above the question what i have tried.